# Cannot perform runtime binding on null reference C# Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, nullreferenceexception

I have found many questions similar to this, but none that solve my issue. I am using SSIS and a C# script to read and modify the styling of an Excel workbook.

I get the following error *"Cannot perform runtime binding on null reference"*. I understand what the error means; essentially you cannot use/reference something that is null. But I thought I was checking for all NULLs within my IF statement.

The code I'm using:

```
     int rows = xlWorkSheetTY.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1;
     Excel.Range rge = xlWorkSheetTY.get_Range("J2:J" + rows, System.Type.Missing);
     foreach (Excel.Range item in rge.Cells)
     {
         if (item != null && (item.Value2 != null || item.Value2 != "" || item.Value2 != "NULL"))
         {
              decimal result = (decimal)0.00;
              if (decimal.TryParse(item.Value2.ToString(), out result))
                        {
                            if (result <= 20)
                            {
                                item.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
                                item.Font.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
                            }
                        }
          }
      }
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to why I am getting this error and what I can do to rectify?

**UPDATE:**
I have inserted a `try catch` statement to try and find some more details about why it was failing. It failed on a specific row every time. I have viewed this row in the raw Excel file and the data is empty.

How can I prevent it from parsing this field without doing what I already have - checking for `nulls` ect?

Comment: put a break in the code and step through it. You will likely get a better error message

Comment: Could it be as simple as splitting up the conditions in your `if` statement? I.e. first only check `if (item != null)` and then have a nested `if` to check the other conditions if the object exists.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Unfortunetley splitting the `if` statement didn't change anything - still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an error in your logic:

```
if (item != null && (item.Value2 != null || item.Value2 != "" || item.Value2 != "NULL"))
```

Suppose that we have e.g. `item.Value2 == null`, then the condition `item.Value2 != ""` returns **`true`**, and it will enter the if-block, causing the error as you described.

In fact I think you should use only `&&` and no `||`:

```
if (item != null && item.Value2 != null && item.Value2 != "" && item.Value2 != "NULL")
```

Comment: HA! It really was that simple - I managed to overcome using the method I posted but this is really what I needed. I cant believe I missed something so trivial. Thanks so much!